# How can I intercept and forward delegate messages in a subclass in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, delegates, objective-c-runtime

I want to implement a subclass of `UIScrollView`, say `MyScrollView`, in Objective-C.

How can I intercept the messages, which are sent from UIScrollView to the delegate, in the implementation of MyScrollView transparently? So the delegate will not realise the interception, as if there's nothing happened.

I have tried to use the message forwarding in Objective-C runtime. I took the MyScrollView as the delegate proxy, intercepting, processing and then forwarding the messages, but it seems things didn't work as I thought.

P.S. I want to expose all the methods as many as superclass(UIScrollView is just an example) offering. And the delegate should not miss any of new messages, which might be added to the superclass in the future, without modifying the implementation of the subclass.

Comment: Could you post the code that you used to implement message forwarding?

Comment: As mentioned in "Item 12: Understand Message Forwarding" in "Effective Objective-C 2.0/ 52 Specific Ways to Improve Your iOS and OS X Programs", the method `-forwardingTargetForSelector:` should be called if `+resolveInstanceMethod:` returns NO. But this didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, this is a very bad idea.**

You shouldn't do this without 100% transparency, users of your code won't be able to understand a thing when something internal breaks due to this.

Here's the recommended approach you should try.

#### MyScrollView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MyScrollView;
@protocol MyScrollViewDelegate <NSObject>

// We will add 'msv_' to all our delegate callbacks
// So it doesn't clash with any of the original 'UIScrollViewDelegate' callbacks
@optional
-(void)msv_scrollViewDidScroll:(MyScrollView *)scrollView;

// You also need to carefully port the 'NS_AVAILABLE_IOS' with each method
// So it's explicitly clear to your users about the availability of a callback
-(void)msv_scrollViewDidZoom:(MyScrollView *)scrollView NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2);

@end


@interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView

// We don't need to set a 'delegate' as that would point to a 'UIScrollView.delegate'
// We are making it explicitly clear what we are doing
@property(nonatomic,weak) id<MyScrollViewDelegate> msvDelegate;


@end
```

#### MyScrollView.m

```
#import "MyScrollView.h"

@interface MyScrollView () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation MyScrollView

// This will get called whenever your scrollView subclass is added to a view
-(void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    [super didMoveToSuperview];

    // Set the delegate for 'UIScrollView' to be self.
    // We will receive all the callbacks from UIScrollView
    // And conditionally forward those to our msvDelegate as needed
    self.delegate = self;
}


#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate Methods

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    // You can do your needed action ***BEFORE*** forwarding a call to your delegate

    if([_msvDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(msv_scrollViewDidScroll:)])
        [_msvDelegate msv_scrollViewDidScroll:self];

    // You can do your needed action ***AFTER*** forwarding a call to your delegate
}


@end
```

Okay, it might seem like a bit verbose at the beginning, but it would pay in the long run. You can guarantee with this approach that you're not messing with runtime and you can immediately fix if anything goes wrong later. You are just adding a layer of abstraction, that's all.

Still not good enough? You have to read through this great article by @mattt -

[Method Swizzling - NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But what about other delegate messages? Should I do the same thing as you just did in scrollViewDidScroll? That would be kinda annoying.

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it the correct way. You decide how many of the methods you want to expose to your MyScrollView users.

Comment: What if I want to expose all the methods as many as super class(UIScrollView is just an example) offering? I might miss some of them if more methods are added to the super class in the future. So I am looking for the proper way to get this done. Thanks though :)

Comment: @LizhenHu Believe me, this is the best way to do this. You can't create something super-automatic, so your users would be recipients of some really weird runtime crashes. You decide to offer every callback, you define it in your protocol for each of them. In future, you keep it updated every year with next iOS releases.

Comment: Yes, I do worry about that would lead to something weird which is hard to debug. Thanks again :)

Comment: @LizhenHu You also need to carefully port the 'NS_AVAILABLE_IOS' with each method. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate is the object responsible for updating the model, hence it should be a controller object not a view, so not a `UIScrollView` subclass.

Instead make a class `NSObject <UIScrollViewDelegate>`. Someone can then create an instance of it in their `UIViewController` and set it as their scroll view's delegate. If they also want to respond to the delegate methods they can set their `UIViewController` to be the delegate and then forward on the method calls to your `UIScrollViewDelegate` implementing subclass, or they might just subclass your object to have less code in their view controller.